# Include a preview image in One Click Demo Import

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress-theming

I want to build a WP demo with the [One Click Demo Import](https://wordpress.org/plugins/one-click-demo-import/) plugin. I have some problems to get it to work.

1- What are the categories for?

```
  'import_file_name' => 'Demo Import 1',
  'categories'       => [ 'Category 1', 'Category 2' ],
```

2- I can't get the preview image to show up.

The code is:

```
'import_preview_image_url'     => 'http://www.your_domain.com/ocdi/preview_import_image1.jpg',
```

I don't want to import it from an url, but include it in the demo. I tried

```
 'local_import_file' => trailingslashit( get_template_directory() ) . 'ocdi/preview.jpg',
```

But that (obviously) doesn't work. When I set it to 'image', the preview of the original theme shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
  'import_preview_image_url'     => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/inc/installation/oc1.jpg',
```

Work perfectly for me.